# How to redirect to login page if user directly visits page in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, global-asax

i am developing one application in mvc my problem is after login it will redirect to some page. if i copy url and paste it in another browser its showing error in application but i need to display home page?

I tried this

in Global.asax

```
 protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["UserName"] = null;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("CurrentCompany", "Company 1");
           // HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Connectionstring", "");
        }
        if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("CurrentCompany", "Company 1");
           // Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Login", action = "Create" });
        }
    }
```

But it is not redirecting my be the problem with Response.RedirectToRoute("Default") or HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute .

Plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will work

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Session["UserName"] = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("CurrentCompany", "Company 1");
       // HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Connectionstring", "");
    }
    if (Session["UserName"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("CurrentCompany", "Company 1");
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Login";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Create";
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        IController controller = new HomeController();
        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        controller.Execute(rc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanq you @Kartikeya Khosla